# Can't install gem 'pg'

Tags: rubygems

My gemfile looks like this

[image]

Then I run bundle install on terminal

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code as **plain text** in the body of your question. Adding it as an image makes it very difficult for people to adapt your code to an answer, you can't copy-paste it, and it's hostile to those dependent on screen-readers

Answer (score 1):

First, I want you to `apt-get installpostgresql`.

Then `apt-get install libpgsql-ruby`,
then `apt-get install libpq-dev`,
then do `apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all`, and finally `gem install pg -v 0.19.0`.

If you are trying to install metasploit, then be sure to run this too after you have finished the above:

```
rvm use 2.3
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest official version is 0.18.4. There is a 0.19.0.pre20160409114042 available as well, but you would need to specify that string exactly in order to install it. So you need to do one of the following:

`gem 'pg', '0.18.4'`

or:

`gem 'pg', '0.19.0.pre20160409114042'`